# How to create models from database tables by sequelize?

Tags: mysql, database, sequelize.js

We can use sequelize to build models and migrate to database tables.But how to use sequelize to create models based on Existing database tables? Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this repository https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto

## Sequelize-Auto

A tool to automatically generate models for SequelizeJS via the command line.

## Install:

```
npm install -g sequelize-auto
```

## Usage:

```
sequelize-auto -h <host> -d <database> -u <user> -x [password] -p [port]  --dialect [dialect] -c [/path/to/config] -o [/path/to/models]
```

Comment: Thanks very much,it really helps a lot!